# How to dock the touch keyboard on the bottom of the touch screen on Windows 11?

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, touch-keyboard

I'm using Windows 11 Pro 22H2 device, OS build 22621.1778.

When I open touch keyboard, it appears at anywhere and I can't dock it to the bottom of the screen. This makes so many inconveniences for me.

After searching on Google, I found that there must be a icon dock on the top right near the close keyboard button but it doesn't exist in my keyboard:

[image: Touch keyboard]

although my OS is on the latest update. So how can I dock the touch keyboard? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, there's a cog icon in top left, don't you have an option to change the position there? That's where it is for me in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks @Destroy666, but when I click to the icon in the top left there is no option to change the position. And as you said, I can dock the keyboard by click this icon in windows 10 but but windows 11 is can not